# Angular 9 - [routerlink] to the actual url (but adding query params)?

Tags: angular, url

I want to navigate to the same current url, only changing one query param.

I can't find any info on how to do this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./']" [queryParams]="{language: 'fr'}">FR</a>
<a [routerLink]="['./']" [queryParams]="{language: 'nl'}">NL</a>
```

I also tried with `window.location.href` but I get an error.

The whole idea is to stay on the same page while switching the language of the app so the `app.component` would intercept the url and change the language of the app.

Thanks for the time you'll spend on this one

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass an empty array instead

```html
<a [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="{language: 'fr'}>FR</a>
<a [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="{language: 'nl'}">NL</a>
```

Comment: I thought I tired it, but indeed it works, thanks m8